# Listing meta_value and converting to INT for comparison

Tags: mysql

I am trying to list all post_id where meta_key = '_length' AND meta_value => 48 however meta_value is LONGTEXT.

I have the first part figured out:

```
SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value
FROM postmeta
WHERE (meta_key = '_length' AND meta_value = '49')

ORDER BY post_id;
```

I tried using Convert and CAST and keep getting errors.  I decided I needed a little help after reading for a few hours.

Comment: *keep getting errors* can you include these error details?

Comment: I figured it out, I was using Cast AS INT instead of CAST AS UNSIGNED, and my parentheses were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After more reading I found an answer.
I believe it was just a two part syntax error.

I was trying

```
SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value
FROM postmeta

WHERE (meta_key = '_length' AND (CAST(meta_value AS INT) > 48))
ORDER BY post_id;
```

However when casting AS I had to switch to UNSIGNED, then I cleaned up the parentheses and the following query works.

```
SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value
FROM postmeta

WHERE (meta_key = '_length' AND CAST(meta_value AS UNSIGNED) > 48)
ORDER BY post_id;
```